Rails 7, How to create file download with button?
Rails 7.1.3
I want to offer a file download to the user with either a button_to or a link_to.
View:
<%= button_to "Download Cat Photo", controller: "my_cont", action: "export", method: :post %>

Controller:
def export
    begin
      tmpzip = Tempfile.new("tmp.zip")

      Zip::OutputStream.open(tmpzip) {|zos|}

      Zip::File.open(tmpzip.path, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zip|
        zip.add("kitty.jpg", "app/assets/images/curiouscat.jpg")
      end

      zip_data = File.read(tmpzip.path)

      send_data(zip_data,
        type: 'application/zip',
        disposition: 'attachment',
        filename: 'kitty.zip')
    ensure
      tmpzip.close
      tmpzip.unlink
    end
end

Results:
After clicking the button, Firefox and Chrome report the error "Form responses must redirect to another location." Trying a "redirect_to" statement at the close of my export action gives a further error that I'm calling either Redirect or Render twice.
The rails console reports "Sent data kitty.zip," so I know the zip file is being created. But the browser never offers the file. I assume it's stuck on the error that FF and Chrome show.
I have tried these alterations to the button: Changed the method to get; added "data: {turbo: :false}" to the button; changed turbo to ":false" as a symbol. Neither change results in anything different reported by the browser console. I have also tried to use a link_to, but that redirects me to Controller#show (also without offering the file for download).
What am I doing wrong here? I'd also appreciate any advice about whether or not a button_to or link_to is more appropriate in this situation.
The Fix
This works when using a link_to:
<%= link_to "Download", {controller: "my_cont", action: "export"} %>

My issue was that I needed a GET route associated with the controller action. Make sure routes includes something similar to:
get "/dashboard/export", to: "dashboard#export"

to see with 'rails routes' command:
dashboard_export GET        /dashboard/export(.:format)         dashboard#export


A download should be a get. Use link_to, you will note that button_to creates a form

@dbugger I've tried: <%= link_to "Download", controller: "my_cont", action: "export", method: :get, target: '_blank' %> with and without the "_blank". The result is always the same. Rails consoler outputs "Processing by Controller#show at HTML" and I'm redirected. It doesn't say "Sent data" is complete; I never see a file offered for download. This is like it bypasses the 'export' action entirely.

Why do you think you want to zip the file? Seems very unneccisary as gzip will transparently compress the file. Also just use a standard GET route for this - not POST.

It's possible you have an error in your method and it is exiting -- add a rescue and see

@max I can switch it to gzip no problem. Trying it, though, I still see "Sent data..." success in my Rails console, but no file offered; GET doesn't change the outcome.

@dbugger Added a rescue; there are no errors.

What happens if you use <%= link_to "Download", {controller: "my_cont", action: "export"}, target: '_blank' %> because your comment suggests link_to is routing to #show. Can you also provide your routes specific to this controller?

@engineersmnky Thanks. This works (with/without the target). The issue was that I didn't have a GET route. In an oversight, I only had a POST. I've edited my post to reflect the fix.

@newser - I'm not talking about manually gzipping the file. I'm talking about adding gzip compression on the transport level when you actually need it. Putting one single file into a zip just seems like something that will annoy your users. KISS.

@max This was a proof of concept using one file only. I wasn't sure what was causing my issue (link? button? my action's content (send_file?)?). Production use will add many files to the zip. Could you explain further how you'd use gzip in a multi-file use case? Maybe create an answer to this question with a quick example? Thanks.
